# Routing error in action show, how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a thank you page, my route for this works fine since I test it the url and works just fine, however when I try to redirect in the create action I get:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schedules", :locale=>:en, :id=>nil}

Controller

```
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])

      if @appointment.save
        #send email
        AppointmentMailer.appointment_confirmation(@appointment).deliver
        AppointmentMailer.new_appointment(@appointment).deliver
        redirect_to :action => "thank_you"
      else
        render :action => 'new', :alert => @appointment.errors.full_messages.split(', ')
      end
  end


  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = @schedule.appointments.new
  end


  def thank_you
      @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Routes

```
  scope ":locale", :locale => /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root :to => "Doctors#index"


    resources :specialties
    resources :branches

    resources :doctors do
       get 'new_schedule', :on => :member, :controller => 'schedules', :action => 'new'
    end

    # NIA: Here is the trick: we remove /shedules/new route (with :except => :new)
    # and map /doctors/new_schedule instead to SchedulesController#new action (see above)
    # (the same is done with appointments)
    resources :schedules, :except => :new do
      get 'new_appointment', :on => :member, :controller => 'appointments', :action => 'new'
    end

    resources :appointments do
      member do
        get :thank_you
      end
    end

  end

  match '*path', :to => redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  match '', :to => redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

Comment: The appointments controller doesn't seem related. Where do you attempt to link to, or use `schedules#show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are wrong. You want this (s/member/collection):

```
resources :appointments do
  collection do
    get :thank_you
  end
end
```

With 'member', your thank you route expects to receive an id which you aren't passing.  Thus it fails.  With collection that won't happen.

Run 'rake routes' before you make this change to see what I'm talking about... then run it after.